# Getting last record from table LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get last record from database 
following is my LINQ query

```
res = context.BgSessions
  .Where(bgs => bgs.BusId == busId && bgs.BusDriverId == locU.Id)
  .OrderByDescending(bgs => bgs.Id)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

& i am checking after that

```
if (res.EndTime == null)
```

Problem here is that even if last session end time is null . 
Somehow this if condition is getting false on production server .I couldn't regenerate this kind of issue on local server

My question is this correct way to get last record using id in LINQ ?

Comment: _"is this correct way to get last record using id in LINQ"_ yes it is. But if you expect the last record to have `EndTime == null` you could include this in the query: `.Where(bgs => ... && bgs.EndTime == null)`

Comment: yes its working properly on my localhost .But somehow its not working on production server

Comment: Probable common mistake: you are connection wrong db!

Comment: @Nikhil: Maybe a race condition, try to include the null check in the `Where` if it's important. Why `EndTime` must be null for the last record?

Comment: i am not checking null in the same query because i am using that record in else condition

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak no db connection is right ..

Comment: Maybe the EndTime in your production is not a nullable column. Try this
if (res.EndTime == null || res.EndTime == SqlDateTime.MinValue)

Comment: its null value @MaulanaMango on production server also